# I got a -1 and I can't delete the question because it is answered now. What should I do?

Tags: support

The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643309/boost-error-vertex-t-is-not-a-type/27643327?noredirect=1). Obviously some users believe that this is a bad question, so since they might be more experienced here than me, I want to "hear" them and remove the question, since, from what I understand, the questions doesn't offer anything to future users.

What I should do? I don't want just to leave it there.

---

EDIT

The question also received two closing votes, but I can't see why!

The reason is:
"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"

Comment: It's not really a big deal. I think I have a couple negative questions, myself. I don't think yours is horrible.

Comment: Well for someone that is a newbie in that specific usage I thought it's not that bad. So you say @AndrewBarber I should just leave it as is? Also note that it has two votes to close!

Comment: @G.Samaras look at what the votes to close are for, identify how you would fix the question based on that feedback, and fix the question.

Comment: Yeah, I would leave it be, myself. Even if it gets closed.

Comment: Thanks Andrew/ @MichaelT see my edit and explain me why this is true about my question and how should I fix it.

Comment: @G.Samaras For long term survival on Stack Overflow, one thing you  need to understand is questions are not necessarily about helping the person that asked the question.  They are about being useful to the larger community and helping everyone.  With your question, it is a code dump that says "I am getting many errors".  How in the world is that useful to anyone else but you.  Who cares that you are getting many errors.  Sorry, but I don't care about that.  What errors, which lines?  List the errors, explain what issue you are facing, and that might be useful.

Comment: The main error is there @psubsee2003. The other errors were similar, or were generated by that main error. I don't think that copy pasting like a fool all the errors would make the question better. That's the reason I am posting you know, I got my programming answer, so I could just continue developing.............but I am asking :)

Comment: Well, in fairness to those who downvoted (and I was NOT one of them - I hadn't seen the question until you linked it here):  if you'd actually *read the words* in the error message and then looked at the line of code it indicated, you probably would have noticed that the two lines above it used `typedef` while the line causing the error used `typename`, and as the error was `<this thing> is not a type` it might have been pretty easy to resolve yourself.The close reason you cited is wrong (it should have been "this is a typo that can't be reproduced" as the reason), however.

Comment: I thought I heard something. Anyway, I agree with @Ken White, I think the "can't be reproduced"/"no longer useful" reason applies here.